# How to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(a_n, b_n)$ exists and be uniqueness?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

Let $f(\cdot, \cdot): R^2\to R$ be a function. Assume that there exists a  constant $C>0$
$$
|f(\cdot, y_1)-f(\cdot, y_2)|\le C|y_1-y_2|.
$$
Then this means the mapping $y\mapsto f(\cdot, y)$ is continuous on $R^2$. Similarly, assume that
$$
|f(x_1, \cdot)-f(x_2, \cdot)|\le C|x_1-x_2|.
$$

Assume that three sequence of real numbers $a_n\to a$, $b_n\to b$ as $n\to \infty$ (the limit exists and finite). Define
$$
c_n=f(a_n, b_n)
$$

Question: How to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} c_n$ exists and be uniqueness?

---

Can I just use the continuity of $f$?
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} c_n =\lim_{n\to \infty} f(a_n, b_n) =f(a,b)?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: a natural candidate for the limit is $f(a,b)$. Observe that
$$
|f(a_n,b_n)-f(a,b)| \leq  |f(a_n,b_n)-f(a_n,b)|+|f(a_n,b)-f(a,b)|.
$$
Uniqueness follows by a similar argument: suppose $c \neq f(a,b)$ is another limit, then $|c-f(a,b)| \leq |c-c_n|+|c_n-f(a,b)|$, so...

Comment: So that should be $\le C_1|b_n-b|+C_2|a_n-a|$? So the limit is true...

Comment: You should try to argue writing down the definition of $a_n \to a$, $b_n \to b$, and $c_n \to f(a,b)$, and then using the hint.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask if we can write $c_n=f(a_n, b)$? I mean I first fix $a_n$ and take $b_nt\to b$.

Comment: No you cannot, in general $c_n = f(a_n,b_n) \neq f(a_n,b)$.